# IBAction won't drag to UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibaction

So I've defined an IBAction in my header, implemented it in my main and I can see it in IB - however, when I drag over the UISearchBar, it doesn't connect.

Here's my header code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface CustomerListViewController : UITableViewController
{
}

-(IBAction)filterTableData:(UISearchBar *)filterBar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *custs, *workingSet;


@end
```

Here's my implementing method:

```
-(IBAction)filterTableData:(UISearchBar *)filterBar {

    //filter our search results
    NSString *filter;
    if (filterBar.text)
        filter = [filterBar.text stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
    else
        filter = @"*";

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE[cd] %@", filter];
    self.workingSet = [self.custs filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And here's an image of IB actually seeing the method and allowing it to be dragged, and me unsuccessfully attempting to drag it to the search bar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7DwC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UISearchBar is not a subclass of a UIControl, meaning that you can't add methods to be called when an event occurs.

What you'll want to do is setup your view controller as a [UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and use the following method instead of your `filterTableData:` method.

`- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`

Then in IB you'll want to click and drag from the search bar to the files owner and choose the delegate property.

Comment: Amazing - worked like a charm.  Will accept after the appropriate time passes.

Comment: I would also include a call to "- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar". This will allow you to remove the keyboard and handle the complete string of characters when the user is done typing. Remove the keyboard with [searchBar resignFirstResponder];